# testability considerations while creating controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I am writing controllers in Web API 2, against which odata queries will be executed:

```
[Route("", Name = "GetAccount")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAccount()
{
    var query = Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.Split('/')[2]; //this query variable will be something "filter=name eq 'alex'"
    var response = _accountService.Get(query);

    if (!response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var readAsAsync = response.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
    if (readAsAsync == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var result = await readAsAsync;
    return Ok(result);
}
```

How do I inject the `Request`, specifically as it relates to: `var query = Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.Split('/')[2];` ?

Here's a very basic test that I've written for this controller:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetAccount_Returns_IHttpActionResultTask()
{
    var accountsService = new Mock<IAccountService>();
    var sut = new AccountsController(accountsService.Object);

    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(sut.GetAccount(), typeof(Task<IHttpActionResult>));
}
```

**In order to test with different values for `Request.RequestUri`...., how do I rewrite my controller to be more testable?**

Comment: You can set the Request property on the apicontroller.

Comment: thank you. can you give an example or point to a resource?

Comment: Noticing some potential issues with the method under test with the mixing of async calls with blocking calls like `.Result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Request` property on the `ApiCntroller`.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetAccount_Returns_IHttpActionResult() {
    //Arrange
    var accountsService = new Mock<IAccountService>();
    var sut = new AccountsController(accountsService.Object);
    sut.Request = new HttpRequestMessage {
        RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost/api/accounts?filter=name")
    };

    //Act
    var result = await sut.GetAccount();

    //Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(IHttpActionResult));
}
```

Also there or some potential blocking issues with the method under test. Mixing async/await with `.Result` blocking calls can cause deadlocks.

Refactor:

```
[Route("", Name = "GetAccount")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAccount() {
    var query = Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.Split('/')[2]; //this query variable will be something "filter=name eq 'alex'"
    var response = await _accountService.Get(query);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var readAsAsync = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
    if (readAsAsync == null) {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var result = await readAsAsync;
    return Ok(result);
}
```